# Reduce Image quality

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm working with Silverlight. I am loading many images(say around 10000) in memory and which gives out of memory exception.So I need to lower the image quality by means of size, resolution and resample the image. Please check my code below.

```
for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
{
  Image img = new Image() { Height = height, Width = width };
  img.Source = writableBimapimg; // returns WriteableBitmap
  container.Children.Add(img);// throws memory exception
}
```

How can I reduce the image quality?

Thanks

Comment: do you really need all the images at once? I would create a thumbnail  of each image to display it in my application. The thumbnail i would store along with the original image.

Comment: yes.i need to load all of them once. I need to reduce the size of the original image itself

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can only reduce the image size if you apply a filter to the image otherwise you get images that loose quality and/or information (I've been through this before).

Unfortunately Silverlight is not a very good platform to do this since it doesn't support any sort of Bilinear, Trilinear or Nearest Neighbour filtering.

In order to reduce the image size using a Nearest Neighbour filter you can add the ImageTools library (Created by Sebastian Stehle) available [here](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/) or as a Nuget Package.

The code to resize the image can be something like this (using ImageTools).

```
   var extendedImage = writableBimapimg.ToImage(); //This is an extension from ImageTools. Make sure you have the "using ImageTools" in the namespaces;
   var resizedImage = ExtendedImage.Resize(extendedImage, width, height, new ImageTools.Filtering.NearestNeighborResizer());
   container.Children.Add(resizedImage.ToBitmap());
```

Now in order to handle those memory issues you need to be carefull with the size you pick for the resized image.

Get a calculator and find out how many images you can load taking into account that the process crashes after 2 GB of RAM is used (for silverlight 4 at least).

Having 32bits per pixel and a resized image of 100x100 pixels you can have thousands of images loaded in memory without any problem.

Hope it helped.